# Elasticsearch : Getting total count based on collapsed value

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and I am trying to extract total number of concurrent users active in the given period.

For example, I have a data set as below:

User    Login Time              Logout Time

A       2020-09-21T10:00:00     2020-09-21T10:30:00

B       2020-09-21T10:00:10     2020-09-21T10:30:15

C       2020-09-21T10:00:08     2020-09-21T10:30:10

D       2020-09-21T10:00:15     2020-09-21T10:30:03

From the above data I want to build below result:

Timestamp           Concurrent Users

2020-09-21T10:00:00     1

2020-09-21T10:00:08     2

2020-09-21T10:00:10     3

2020-09-21T10:00:15     4

2020-09-21T10:30:00     4

2020-09-21T10:30:03     3

2020-09-21T10:30:10     2

2020-09-21T10:30:15     1

My understanding is we can do this in two steps

1. Extract unique login and logout time
2. _count the value based on filter (logout time lte given time, login time gte given time)

I would like to know is it possible to extract the result in single query?

I am working in version 7.9.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this by setting a new field "session" as a date_range
with gte: logintime et lte: logouttime

Then you will be able to do a date_histogramm.

Please find below a small test case:

```
PUT test/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
      "date_range_test": {
        "type": "date_range"
      }
    }
 
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "title": "test1",
  "date_range_test": {
    "gte": "2020-01-01",
    "lte": "2020-01-05"
  }
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "title": "test1",
  "date_range_test": {
    "gte": "2020-01-02",
    "lte": "2020-01-05"
  }
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "title": "test2",
  "date_range_test": {
    "gte": "2020-01-02",
    "lte": "2020-01-07"
  }
}


POST test/_doc
{
  "title": "test3",
  "date_range_test": {
    "gte": "2020-01-07",
    "lte": "2020-01-08"
  }
}

GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sessions": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date_range_test",
        "fixed_interval": "1d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the response

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "sessions" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1577836800000,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1577923200000,
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-01-03T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1578009600000,
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-01-04T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1578096000000,
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1578182400000,
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1578268800000,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-01-07T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1578355200000,
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-01-08T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1578441600000,
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```